# opening up an html help page with for my application

Tags: java, awt

I have a program that has a help jmenuItem that will open the html "help.html" file I made specifically for the program guidance. So i want it to pop from the Default browser reading it from the same path that contains my program. My html file name is  "help.html". How would I go about getting it. The following is what I have tried I am doing it wrong somehow, any kind of help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
         try{ 
            String url = "help.html"; 
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url)); 
            } 
              catch (java.io.IOException e1)
             { 
              System.out.println(e1.getMessage()); 
            }
```

Comment: *"reading it from the same path that contains my program."* If this is an applet or is launched using JWS, getting the 'installation path' will not be possible.  Why not display the help in a `JEDitorPane`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new File(url).toURL())
```

Comment: Hi Serge, I think its working but it can't find the file, i believe its the "String url = help.html", I think there is more I need to specify in the url string rather than just "help.html", I think that it will eventually lead me to the solution, any idea on why it might be doing that ? Thank you Serge.

Comment: Most likely because you run your app from IDE and it sets current directory to the root folder of your project, not to the folder where it stores the jar file. so if you open your shell window and change to directory where the jar file resides and then you make sure that help.html exist there and then you launch your app with 'java -jar ...' command then it will work as you expect

Comment: Thanks Serge, it really helped me out

Comment: Hi Serge, I can't mark it, I already tried several times, it requires me to at least have 15 reputation points and I am still new to the forum, I only have 11 points so far.

Comment: )) Ok, Raymond, I understood. Good luck)